# Java inner private class and variables within class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, private, inner-classes

If I have an inner class that is private, what should the access modifiers on my variables be in that class?

Should I also make them private?

For example:

```
private class MyClass {
  public String name; // what would this do?

}
```

In the above example, since the class is private, but the variable `name` is public, who has access to it?

Comment: That isn't valid Java syntax, and it depends on if you return a **reference** to the inner class.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch changed syntax, pls check